# creating video file in C#

Tags: c#, screen-capture

How would I create an application that records the users interactions with the desktop in C# and then convert it to a video format such as avi?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to capture screen to be video using C# .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068414/how-to-capture-screen-to-be-video-using-c-sharp-net)

Answer (score 0):

To capture screenshots you can use [CopyFromScreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen).

Simple C# example:

```cs
Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
using(Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
{
    using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
         g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
    }

    // TODO: Save or use in any other way.
}
```

However, if you want to capture videos, it would be better to use something like [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068414/how-to-capture-screen-to-be-video-using-c-sharp-net).