# How can I capture the screen to be video using C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, video, video-capture

Is there some library to capture a screen to be a compressed video file or some solution that can do it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your best option seems to be Windows Media Encoder.

Here are some resources:

- *[Capture Desktop Activities As a Movie](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/armoghanasif/CaptureDesktopActivities11122005013755AM/CaptureDesktopActivities.aspx)*
- *[Capture Activities on Screen in a Movie](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/CaptureScreenAsVideo.aspx)*
- *[Capture screen activities/video using WmEncoder](http://mycomponent.blogspot.com/2009/04/capture-screen-activitiesvideo-using.html)*

Comment: I looking for DirectshowNet, but I don't know what should I use the input filter for screen capture.

Comment: The last link seems to be broken (on the way to time out), but it is "just" ***extremely*** slow. It took more than 4 minutes...

Answer (score 50):

This code uses SharpAvi available on NuGet.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SharpAvi;
using SharpAvi.Codecs;
using SharpAvi.Output;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Captura
{
    // Used to Configure the Recorder
    public class RecorderParams
    {
        public RecorderParams(string filename, int FrameRate, FourCC Encoder, int Quality)
        {
            FileName = filename;
            FramesPerSecond = FrameRate;
            Codec = Encoder;
            this.Quality = Quality;

            Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
            Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
        }

        string FileName;
        public int FramesPerSecond, Quality;
        FourCC Codec;

        public int Height { get; private set; }
        public int Width { get; private set; }

        public AviWriter CreateAviWriter()
        {
            return new AviWriter(FileName)
            {
                FramesPerSecond = FramesPerSecond,
                EmitIndex1 = true,
            };
        }

        public IAviVideoStream CreateVideoStream(AviWriter writer)
        {
            // Select encoder type based on FOURCC of codec
            if (Codec == KnownFourCCs.Codecs.Uncompressed)
                return writer.AddUncompressedVideoStream(Width, Height);
            else if (Codec == KnownFourCCs.Codecs.MotionJpeg)
                return writer.AddMotionJpegVideoStream(Width, Height, Quality);
            else
            {
                return writer.AddMpeg4VideoStream(Width, Height, (double)writer.FramesPerSecond,
                    // It seems that all tested MPEG-4 VfW codecs ignore the quality affecting parameters passed through VfW API
                    // They only respect the settings from their own configuration dialogs, and Mpeg4VideoEncoder currently has no support for this
                    quality: Quality,
                    codec: Codec,
                    // Most of VfW codecs expect single-threaded use, so we wrap this encoder to special wrapper
                    // Thus all calls to the encoder (including its instantiation) will be invoked on a single thread although encoding (and writing) is performed asynchronously
                    forceSingleThreadedAccess: true);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Recorder : IDisposable
    {
        #region Fields
        AviWriter writer;
        RecorderParams Params;
        IAviVideoStream videoStream;
        Thread screenThread;
        ManualResetEvent stopThread = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        #endregion

        public Recorder(RecorderParams Params)
        {
            this.Params = Params;

            // Create AVI writer and specify FPS
            writer = Params.CreateAviWriter();

            // Create video stream
            videoStream = Params.CreateVideoStream(writer);
            // Set only name. Other properties were when creating stream, 
            // either explicitly by arguments or implicitly by the encoder used
            videoStream.Name = "Captura";

            screenThread = new Thread(RecordScreen)
            {
                Name = typeof(Recorder).Name + ".RecordScreen",
                IsBackground = true
            };

            screenThread.Start();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            stopThread.Set();
            screenThread.Join();

            // Close writer: the remaining data is written to a file and file is closed
            writer.Close();

            stopThread.Dispose();
        }

        void RecordScreen()
        {
            var frameInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1 / (double)writer.FramesPerSecond);
            var buffer = new byte[Params.Width * Params.Height * 4];
            Task videoWriteTask = null;
            var timeTillNextFrame = TimeSpan.Zero;

            while (!stopThread.WaitOne(timeTillNextFrame))
            {
                var timestamp = DateTime.Now;

                Screenshot(buffer);

                // Wait for the previous frame is written
                videoWriteTask?.Wait();

                // Start asynchronous (encoding and) writing of the new frame
                videoWriteTask = videoStream.WriteFrameAsync(true, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                timeTillNextFrame = timestamp + frameInterval - DateTime.Now;
                if (timeTillNextFrame < TimeSpan.Zero)
                    timeTillNextFrame = TimeSpan.Zero;
            }

            // Wait for the last frame is written
            videoWriteTask?.Wait();
        }

        public void Screenshot(byte[] Buffer)
        {
            using (var BMP = new Bitmap(Params.Width, Params.Height))
            {
                using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(BMP))
                {
                    g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, new Size(Params.Width, Params.Height), CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

                    g.Flush();

                    var bits = BMP.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, Params.Width, Params.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
                    Marshal.Copy(bits.Scan0, Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
                    BMP.UnlockBits(bits);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Example Usage

1. Create a console application.
2. Add Reference to `System.Drawing` and `System.Windows.Forms`. (The usage of `System.Windows.Forms` can be avoided if you modify the code).
3. Install SharpAvi from NuGet.

Code:

```
using Captura;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Using MotionJpeg as Avi encoder,
            // output to 'out.avi' at 10 Frames per second, 70% quality
            var rec = new Recorder(new RecorderParams("out.avi", 10, SharpAvi.KnownFourCCs.Codecs.MotionJpeg, 70));

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to Stop...");
            Console.ReadKey();

            // Finish Writing
            rec.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe a little bit more here?

Comment: The app uses user32.dll and gdi32.dll to capture screenshots and writes them into the AviWriter along with audio captured using WaveIn api

Comment: Worked for me!  Thanks for share it Mathew!

Comment: What is FourCC here.

Comment: FourCC stands for 4 'character code'. It is a type defined in SharpAvi, used to identify an encoder installed in the system.

Comment: SharpAvi contains a class: KnownFourCCs.Codecs which contains FourCCs of codecs like MotionJPEG, Xvid, x264, etc.

Comment: What should I pass as FourCC argument

Comment: Try passing `KnownFourCCs.Codecs.MotionJpeg`.

Comment: It is implemented in SharpAvi and should work even if your system does not have any codecs available.

Comment: Thankyou Mathew Sachin its recording video but how to save this recording

Comment: I added an example usage in the answer. Hope that it will answer your question.

Comment: Mathew I did not find save output file please tell me how to save output as mp4 or other video format.

Comment: Why captured video has speed x2 or even x3?

Comment: This SharpAvi is speeding up videos, regardless of how slow I feed him bitmaps, even when I added blocking queue. Don't waist your time on the code above.

Comment: Additionaly even Captura standalone app has exactly the same performance issues on Xeon, 32GB Ram, 500GB SSD, Quadro 2000 laptop.

Comment: Issue with `RecorderParams` constructor in VB. It seems case insensitive, so when creating a new `Recorder` object with `RecorderParams` threw a null filepath exception. The parameter was setting to itself. Fixed by adding an underscore in the constructor arguments, to `filename`. Other than that, great answer. Couldn't have been any easier.

Comment: Amazing staff, what about put the link to github to the end? Since the code in the page is great enough. The git hub project run with errors.

Comment: How to capture sound at the same time?

Comment: When I use SharpAVI in my app on full RDP desktop it works fine. But if my app is launched through RemoteApp, without full desktop, It doesn't let my app to load at all.