# c# event when something on screen changes

Tags: c#, windows, com-interop

Not sure if it's possible. I searched, but could not find a solution to this question...

What I'm trying to do is write something that tracks changes on the screen (changes are not related to my app - I'm just subscribing to any change by any software that changes something on the screen). For example, if there is a movie playing on Windows Media Player - than the display keeps on changing - all the time. Or another example is some animation in IE (or any other browser / app) that shows on the screen. I would like my app to be notified that there is "movement" on the screen, and if possible, the area where movement occurred.

Is such thing possible?

Comment: This is possible, but I don't know how. But a similar problem would be capturing screen activities as a movie. So maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/4124382/4136669 can help.

Comment: There is an `EventViewer` in windows. I think you have to do something with that.

Comment: I think you have to hook the message queue's from the running applications and have to look for wm_paint messages. Do a search for hook creation/injection on windows or global system hooks.