# Screen capture (video) using C# .NET on Windows 10

Tags: c#-4.0, video, windows-10

I'd like to get started doing screen capture (of video content) on Windows 10 (specifically on a laptop), using C#.  My preference is to code in a [Windows Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application, but I'd consider a [UWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform) application if that was easier.

There's a lot of material on the web, but I'm not sure where to start as it's usually older content or about DirectShow which requires the use of C++ (e.g. "Windows Media" → "The Windows Development Reference: Audio and Video in Desktop Apps" → "[Audio and Video](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/ee663260(v=vs.85).aspx)").

There's the Stack Overflow question "[How can I capture the screen to be video using C# .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068414/how-to-capture-screen-to-be-video-using-c-sharp-net)", but that's from 2010 and uses (presumably) depreciated software versions as the core.

Comment: Do you want to stream video, audio, and images to other devices on your local network?

Comment: No, I want to capture video content running on my local machine

Comment: @AndriiKrupka - I was wanting to capture the video stream and pass it to another applications API in C#.  Would you have some guidance?

Comment: Maybe you should post it as a new question @SalVelazquez

Comment: @SalVelazquez , I'll provide an answer on a new topic.

Comment: Hi! I have an answer about my app on the same question. It's made using WPF: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32797504/5377194

Comment: You can view the project on GitHub: https://github.com/MathewSachin/Captura