# Using SharpAVI to record the screen, why is the .avi file playing back as if its sped up when I increase the FPS?

Tags: c#, .net, avi, screen-recording, screencast

I'm working on a project where I need to record the desktop during an event started by the user. I found [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32797504/8908365) which has been really helpful, since I am new to C#.

However, when I increase the FPS in the Recorder Params in main, the outputted video file is sped up drastically. It seems to be speeding up in relation to how much you increase the FPS by.

I've tried to look into why this might be happening, but I can't find any  documentation on SharpAVI or on Captura. Can anyone shed some light on why this might be happening? It would be really nice to be able to have a 30 FPS avi, and for the sake of learning, I'd really like to know whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested this is an issue i had. I found you have to timestamp each of the frames individually as the media player you are using doesnt know when to update the frame so by default just updates them as quickly as possible.